# Unable to execute a file in the hard disk partition

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

My computer has two hard disks (1 SSD + 1 HDD). I have installed operating systems in SSD and made HDD as a NTFS drive (named as 'WorkData'; and the location is `/media/WorkData`), so that I can work in that HDD from both Ubuntu and Windows.

I have compiled a program (named as 'chem') in 'WorkData' and tried executing it by `./chem` command. However, I am getting the error 'bash: `./chem`: Permission denied'.

I tried following ways to fix it:

1. Used, `chmod u+x chem` => No use.
2. Tried the option in the link => No use.
3. Tried the option in the link => No use.

Can some one help me in this regard?

Comment: does it work if you use sudo? who is teh files owner/group? if you use `chmod o+x chem` does that fix it?

Comment: Ubuntu can read a NTFS partition, but it won't obey the permission on it, since it knows nothing about how to do that.  So this permission problem is a Linux permission problem

Answer (score 0):

mount the partition with the `exec` option, specified after the `users` option, or specify a `umask` of 022 as a mount option

Comment: Can you explain what these commands actually do?

Comment: the `exec` option grants all permissions checks the ability to run executables on that disk. The `umask` option says "permissions on this disks will be 755 for all directories" which gives everyone the right to run executables. Since Linux doesn't "get" NTFS in a native fashion, you are using the disks mount options to establish global permissions for the disk that linux **can** use.